# Error message saying count is not defined

Tags: python, syntax-error

Here is the full script:

```
import random

aNumber=random.randrange(100)+1
print("I am thinking of a number 1 through 100.")
if aNumber>50:
    print("It has a value greater than 50.")
else:
    print("It has a value less than or equal to 50.")
while True:
    answer=int(raw_input("What is your guess?\n"))
    count+=1
    if aNumber==answer:
        print("Congratulations, you have guessed the number!")
    elif aNumber<answer:
        print("Try a lower number")
    elif aNumber>answer:
        print("Try a higher number")
```

Here is the error message I am getting:

```
line 11, in <module>
    count+=1
NameError: name 'count' is not defined
```

Comment: @Carcigenicate exactly. Also you should read [this article on scopes](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_scope.asp)

Answer (score 3):

You need to define `count` prior to increasing its value through the `+= 1` operator. Indeed, `count += 1` is equivalent to `count = count + 1` and thus count must be defined before (e.g.: `count = 0` at the beginning of your script).

Answer (score 0):

Count is not defined before `count += 1`, you should probably declare it above your while loop like so:

```
import random

aNumber=random.randrange(100)+1
print("I am thinking of a number 1 through 100.")
if aNumber>50:
    print("It has a value greater than 50.")
else:
    print("It has a value less than or equal to 50.")
count = 0 ##### define it here
while True:
    answer=int(raw_input("What is your guess?\n"))
    count+=1
    if aNumber==answer:
        print("Congratulations, you have guessed the number!")
    elif aNumber<answer:
        print("Try a lower number")
    elif aNumber>answer:
        print("Try a higher number")
```

Answer (score 0):

This works if I am not mistaken.

```
import random
aNumber = random.randrange(100)+1
print("I am thinking of a number 1 through 100.")
if aNumber>50:
    print("It has a value greater than 50.")
else:
    print("It has a value less than or equal to 50.")

count = 0 # count is a variable name and it has to be defined beforehand of using
while True:
    answer=int(input("What is your guess? \n"))
    count+=1
    if aNumber == answer:
        print("Congratulations, you have guessed the number!")
    elif aNumber < answer:
        print("Try a lower number")
    else:
        print("Try a higher number") # since this is the remaining condition, you can simply use else
```